# Redirect to another SubController using MVC

Tags: java, url, redirect, model-view-controller, web

I'm new in developing web applications in Java and I'm really struggling with a problem. My web application needs to fulfil two primary tasks (in short):

- User selects location (mainfloor, floor1, etc.) -> floor plan of the selected floor shows up -> user can tag his exact location on the plan
- User searches another user -> appropriate floor plan with the searched user tagged shows up

So far, my project contains (most important parts):

- FrontController

  ```js
  public class FrontController extends HttpServlet {

    private static final String SEITE = "/WEB-INF/jsp/navi/index.jsp";
    private Map < String, Controller > controller;

    @
    Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
      controller = new HashMap < String, Controller > ();
      controller.put("/start", new StartSubController(this));
      // controller.put("/floors/mainfloor", new FloorSubController(this));
      // controller.put("/floors/1og", new FloorSubController(this));
      controller.put("/floors/2og", new FloorSubController(this));
      // controller.put("/floors/3og", new FloorSubController(this));
    }

    @
    Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

      // /whereami/test/eins.do ohne /whereami und .do ==> /test/eins
      String navi = request.getRequestURI().substring( // /whereami/test/eins.do
        request.getContextPath().length(), // /whereami
        request.getRequestURI().length() - 3); // .do

      Controller c = controller.get(navi);
      if (c != null) {
        try {
          navi = c.execute(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          throw new ServletException(e);
        }
      }

      // Die URL f�r das Fragment
      request.setAttribute("url", "/WEB-INF/jsp" + navi + ".jsp");

      RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(SEITE);
      rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    @
    Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
      doGet(request, response);
    }
  }
  ```
- front page where the user can choose between these two taks (start.jsp and StartSubController)
  start.jsp

  ```html
  <form name="sendeEtageOrUser" method="post">
    <div id="waehle-etage" style="display:none;">
      <br>Bitte geben Sie die Etage ihres aktuellen Aufenthaltsortes an:
      <select class="select-etage" name="floor">
        <option value="Erdgeschoss">Erdgeschoss</option>
        <option value="1OG">1.OG</option>
        <option value="2OG">2.OG</option>
        <option value="3OG">3.OG</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <input id="submit-button-etage" name="geschoss-button" type="submit" value="Bestätigen"></input>
    </div>

    <div id="suche-user-standort" style="display:none;">
      <br>Bitte geben Sie Name oder Kennung des gesuchten Users ein:
      <input type="text" name="userNameOrKennung"></input>
      <br>
      <input id="submit-button-suche-user" name="user-button" type="submit" value="Suchen"></input>
    </div>
  </form>
  ```

StartSubController

```js
public class StartSubController implements Controller {

  private FrontController frontController;
  private DBManager dbManager;
  private String userOrKennung;

  private final String GESCHOSS_BUTTON = "geschoss-button";
  private final String USER_BUTTON = "user-button";

  public StartSubController(FrontController frontController) {
    this.frontController = frontController;
  }

  @
  Override
  public String execute(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    // /whereami/test/one.do without /whereami and .do ==> /test/one
    String navi = request.getRequestURI().substring( // /whereami/test/one.do
      request.getContextPath().length(), // /whereami
      request.getRequestURI().length() - 3); // .do

    if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
      if (request.getParameter(GESCHOSS_BUTTON).equals("Bestätigen")) {
        // Redirection to controller and to chosen floor
        String floor = request.getParameter("floor");
        if (floor != null) {
          // TODO: Redirect to /whereiam/floors/xog.do
        }
      } else if (request.getParameter(USER_BUTTON).equals("Suchen")) {
        userOrKennung = request.getParameter("userNameOrKennung");
        try {
          if (searchUserInDB(userOrKennung) != null || searchUserInDB(userOrKennung).equals(null)) {
            // TODO: Redirect to /whereiam/floors/xog.do
          }
        } catch (SqlException e) {
          // TODO Handle SqlException
          throw (RuntimeException) new RuntimeException()
            .initCause(e);
        }
      }
    }
    return navi;
  }
}
```

Now my problem: I don't understand how to redirect via StartSubController to http://localhost:8080/whereAmI/floors/2og.do?
I know that I can't use response.sendRedirect(..) and a return "/floors/2og" in the execute method of the StartSubController won't change the URL on the client side. But I think I need to change the URL to make the following FloorSubController work with the following jsp.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you writing all of this by hand instead of using existing ready-to-go implementations such as Spring MVC?

Comment: That would have been my second question. Will using Spring solve my problem?

Comment: Yes. If you use Spring, particularly Spring Boot, all of the infrastructure is done for you. (And I recommend Thymeleaf instead of JSP, but that's a matter of preference.)

Comment: Alright, thank you! Then I'm gonna try using Spring.